# Iframe html body is refering to localhost

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When i hit one api it is giving me HTML content and I want to display them in a iframe , that content has javascript and css files which is referred as

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/scripts/main/backend.js"></script>`

So it is trying to fetch data from localhost/content/scripts/main/backend.js

How can I set it to particular domain?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="mydomin.com/content/scripts/main/backend.js"></script> like this

Comment: yes script and other inline css also

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the desired domain to all `src`s in the HTML string you receive. Something like this:

```
let myHTMLString = getHTMLFromSomeAPI();

myHTMLString.replace(/src="/g, 'src="http://my-domain');

...

//Set to iFrame
```

Comment: that is true but if in one of script file it is written that window.location.replace to lets say "/ls/1". 
that will be obviously refer to localhost

Comment: You need to replace the strings of those places which don't have src too.